# Why cherrypick merge?

Tags: svn, merge

What's the point of cherrypick merging. Why don't you just merge the whole thing. Cherrypick merging seems risky like what happens if you pick the wrong commit or only pick some of the commits surely it's just safer to merge normally (sync merge then do a reintegrate merge) instead of doing a sync merge and then

`svn merge -c 12 ^/project_name/branches/3` OR a range of commits 

`svn merge -r 12:100 ^/project_name/branches/3`

in the trunk and or other branches which will be released

What are the benefits of cherrypick merging in comparison to normal reintegrate merging? - It seems more risky and more work to do cherrypick merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do a normal reintegrate merge then do so.

Cherrypicking is for when you can't.

For instance, a bug is found in the current release.  You fix it in the trunk, then it's decided that you need to get it out quicker than the next release.

You can't reintegrate trunk back to the release branch, so you cherry pick the commits that make up that particular fix.

Comment: "You can't reintegrate trunk back to the release branch, so you cherry pick the commits that make up that particular fix." Why not?

Comment: @Mark Imagine your trunk is not always shippable, i.e. you do new feature development in the trunk.  You wouldn't want to merge all, possibly incomplete, development into your production-ready release branch.  So you take just the bug fix.

Comment: Even if the trunk is shippable, you may not want to ship it.  Nor would you want to merge all the changes in what will be v2 back into the v1 branch.

Comment: I believe the trunk should always be stable.
@Charles I agree completely, since if you merged the whole trunk then you wouldn't really have new versions being pushed out but bug fixes pushed with new features.